# Duality mappings on finite-dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a few questions regarding some concepts in a book "nonlinear partial differential equations by Roubicek" I am studying. The following is from the text.

"Let $V$ be a separable, reflexive Banach space. Let $V_{k}$ be a finite-dimensional subspace. Since $V$ is finite dimensional we can identify $V_{k} \cong V_{k}^{*}$. If necessary, we can re-norm the finite dimensional $V_{k}$ to impose a Hilbert structure($V_{k}$ is then homeomorphic with a Euclidean space).

We consider the duality mapping $J$ which is taken as $J(u):= \{f \in V^{*}; \langle f,u \rangle = \Vert u|\Vert^{2} = \Vert f \Vert_{*}^{2}\}$. If $V$ is a separable Banach space and $V^{*}$ is strictly convex then $J$ is single valued.

We then have that $J_{k}: V_{k} \rightarrow V_{k}^{*}$ is single valued and a linear homeomorphism such that $\langle J_{k}u, u \rangle = \Vert u \Vert_{V_{k}}^{2}$, $\Vert J_{k}u \Vert_{V_{k}^{*}} = \Vert u \Vert_{V_{k}}$  "

Questions:

1. What exactly is meant by "re-norm $V_{k}$ to impose a Hilbert structure", how would you do that?
2. How does it follow that the duality mapping $J_{k}$ is a linear homeomorphism?
3. Is the duality mapping $J_{k}$ a surjective isometry or just an isometry?
4. How exactly is $V_{k}$ homeomorphic to a Euclidean space?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fix a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_m \in V_k$. Then the map $\sum \alpha_jv_j\to\left(\sum |\alpha_j|^2\right)^{1/2}$ defines a norm on $V_k$, and this norm is induced by the inner product $\langle \sum \alpha_jv_j,\sum \beta_jv_j\rangle = \sum \alpha_j\overline{\beta_j}$. In a finite-dimensional space all norms are equivalent, so the identity map becomes a homeomorphism if we consider the original norm in the domain and this new norm in the codomain. In the new norm, $V_k$ is a Hilbert space.

2/3. You can see that $\|J_ku\|_{V_k^*}=\|u\|_{V_k}$; this proves that $J_k$ is an isometry. In particular, it is injective. So $J_k:V_k\to V_k^*$ is an injective map between two finite-dimensional spaces of the same dimension, and so it is also surjective. This means that $J_k$ is a linear homeomorphism.

$4.$ This is the same as 1.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your response. Are you familiar with the book "Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications" by Roubicek by any chance?

Comment: Hi John,  you are welcome,  and I'm afraid not.

Comment: @MartinArgerami How do we show that $J_{k}$ is linear? Can you maybe give a hint of how to show?

Comment: @MartinArgerami is this fine for the first part: Let $J(\lambda u) = f_{\lambda}$ such that $\langle f_{\lambda}, \lambda u \rangle = \Vert \lambda u \Vert^{2} = \Vert f_{\lambda} \Vert^{2}_{*}$ then let $J(u) = f_{u}$ such that $\langle f_{u},u \rangle = \Vert u \Vert^{2} = \Vert f_{u} \Vert_{*}^{2}$. We want to show that $f_{\lambda} = \lambda f_{u}$. If we define $\langle \lambda f_{u}, v \rangle := \langle f_{u}, \lambda v \rangle$ then  $\langle \lambda f_{u}, u \rangle = \langle f_{u}, \lambda u \rangle = \Vert \lambda u \Vert^{2} = \Vert \lambda f_{u} \Vert^{2}$.

Comment: Since $J$ is single-valued it must be that $f_{\lambda} = \lambda f$.

Comment: The way it is defined, $J$ is in general not linear: you can check that if $V=\ell^3(\mathbb Z_2)$, then $V^*=L^{3/2}(\mathbb Z_2)$; you have $J(1,0)=(1,0)$, $J(0,1)=(0,1)$, but $J(1,1)\ne(1,1)$. When you consider $\ell^2(\mathbb Z_n)$, then its dual is also $\ell^2(\mathbb Z_n)$, and $J(u)=u$. I think that they book is trying to say this, in a fancy (and confusing) way.

Comment: @MartinArgerami If it is not linear in general then how are we sure that it is linear in this case?

Comment: When you consider $V_k$ as a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and think of the natural identification of $V_k^*$ with $V_k$, then $J$ is the identity, so it is trivially linear.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Sorry if these questions are trivial but I have only recently gotten back into this. How would you define the "natural identification"?

Comment: The Riesz Representation Theorem tells you that any bounded functional $f$on a Hilbert space $H$ is of the form $f:h\mapsto\langle h,k\rangle$ for some $k\in H$. It is not hard to see that the map $f\mapsto k$ is an isometric isomorphism from $H^*$ onto $H$. In other words, we can identify $H^*$ with $H$.